# Security group and subnet belong to different networks error when setting up Aurora with a Bastion Host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am attempting to set up a RDS Aurora cluster with an associated Bastion host for access. I am receiving the following error

```
Security group sg-0e71d565ec5decfd9 and subnet subnet-c2cda1aa belong to different networks. 
(Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; 
Request ID: 68495593-198a-416a-84b5-f35439f040c3)
```

I am quite confused as to what is causing this as I am specifying the VPC id for this script explicitly.
I am passing in

```
VpcId: vpc-0e613d6fe837e387f
VpcSecurityGroupId: sg-03d5dd202625be5c5
```

My best guess regarding the cause is that the bastion security group is defaulting to a specific network, I however cant seem to figure out how to remedy this.

My cloudformation script is as follows

```
Description: Set up a serverles PostgreSQL cluster with a bastion host (using Aurora)

Parameters: 
    DatabaseName:
            Type: String
    EngineVersion:
            Type: String
            Default: 11.4
    MasterUsername:
            Type: String
            Default: root
    MasterUserPassword:
            Type: String
            Default: root1234
            NoEcho: true
    VpcId:
            Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
    VpcSecurityGroupId:
            Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id
    DBSubnetGroupName:
            Type: String
    BastionImageId:
            Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>
            Default: /aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn-ami-hvm-x86_64-ebs
    BastionKeyName:
            Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
            Description: EC2 key used to connect to the bastion host
    DeletionProtection:
            Type: String
            Default: false
            AllowedValues:
            - true
            - false

Resources:
    Cluster:
            Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
            Properties:
                    Engine: aurora-postgresql
                    EngineVersion: !Ref EngineVersion
                    DatabaseName: !Ref DatabaseName
                    MasterUsername: !Ref MasterUsername
                    MasterUserPassword: !Ref MasterUserPassword
                    DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref AWS::StackName
                    DBClusterParameterGroupName: !Ref DBParameterGroup
                    DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref DBSubnetGroupName
                    BackupRetentionPeriod: 35
                    DeletionProtection: !Ref DeletionProtection
                    VpcSecurityGroupIds:
                    - !Ref VpcSecurityGroupId
    DBParameterGroup:                                                                                                     
            Type: AWS::RDS::DBClusterParameterGroup
            Properties:
                    Description: The parameter group for the discourse DB cluster
                    Family: aurora-postgresql11
                    Parameters:
                            client_encoding: 'UTF8' 
    BastionSecurityGroup:
            Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
            Properties:
                    GroupDescription: !Sub Bastion for ${AWS::StackName}
                    SecurityGroupEgress:
                    - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
                      FromPort: -1
                      ToPort: -1
                      IpProtocol: -1
                    - DestinationSecurityGroupId: !Ref VpcSecurityGroupId
                      IpProtocol: tcp
                      FromPort: 3306
                      ToPort: 3306
                    SecurityGroupIngress: []
                    VpcId: !Ref VpcId
    Bastion: 
            Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
            Properties: 
                    DisableApiTermination: true
                    ImageId: !Ref BastionImageId
                    InstanceType: t2.nano
                    KeyName: !Ref BastionKeyName
                    Monitoring: false
                    SecurityGroupIds:
                    - !Ref VpcSecurityGroupId
                    - !Ref BastionSecurityGroup
                    UserData: !Base64 'yum install postgresql --assumeyes' # if this script does not work this line  broke it 

Outputs:
    Host: 
            Value: !GetAtt Cluster.Endpoint.Address
            Export:
                    Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}Host
    Name:
            Value: !Ref DatabaseName
            Export:
                    Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}Name
    BastionHost:
            Value: !GetAtt Bastion.PublicDnsName
            Export:
                    Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}BastionHost
    BastionIp:
            Value: !GetAtt Bastion.PublicIp
            Export:
                    Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}BastionIp
    BastionSecurityGroupId:
            Value: !GetAtt BastionSecurityGroup.GroupId
            Export:
                    Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}BastionSecurityGroupId
```

Answer (score -1):

The error looks fairly self explanatory. You may be passing a VPC ID explicitly, but you are also passing a VPC Security Group ID and a Subnet Group name explcitly as well. From your error, it looks like you are passing `sg-0e71d565ec5decfd9` and `subnet-c2cda1aa` respectively, but clearly that security group and the subnets int he subnet group are not part of the same VPC. Do cross check that in your setup.

Comment: I double checked and I am not passing those values in as parameters, I have updated the question with my VPC and VPCSecurityGroupIds

Comment: If you are not explicitly passing a subnet group name, then it's using the "default" subnet group (automatically created by RDS) in your account. Default subnet group is created in your "default" vpc, and not the vpc you specified. Can you explicitly create a subnet group in the vpc you are specifying and try with that?

Comment: Also, go to EC2 dashboard in your console, go to subnets, and spot the subnet from the error message. And check which vpc id it belongs to. I'll be surprised if it is in the same vpc id you specify in your request.

Comment: Any update on this? I’m fairly sure this can be resolved easily. Let me know where you are.